# Sphinx not autodocumenting decorated Celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, python-sphinx

I'm trying to run Sphinx to document the following Celery task, but am getting an empty document upon generating the Sphinx docs:

```
@celery.task(name='taskname')
def taskname(data):
    """
    Some documentation

    """
    ...
```

...whereas the following gets documented fine:

```
def non_decorated_function(data):
    """
    Some documentation

    """
    ...
```

I understand that the function signature gets mangled by the celery task decorator, but I thought that the following in conf.py was supposed to fix that:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'celery.contrib.sphinx',
]
```

My .rst file looks like this:

```
.. automodule:: tasks
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Using autotask *does* work, but I was hoping to get this working with automodule, as I'm adding this to a significant codebase:

```
.. automodule:: tasks
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
.. autotask:: tasks.taskname
```

Is there any way to fix the celery tasks decorator to be supported by Sphinx documentation?

Comment: You need new line turn `"""Some documentation"""` to `"""Some documentation{enter key here}"""`

Comment: This happens regardless of newline state; sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Are you sure? pay attention at your edit it's not the right format. `"""description{enter}"""`

Comment: I'm sure, but I've updated my example to reflect that. I'm generating docs for 2 functions in tandem, with the only difference being the decorator.

Comment: Have you tried `autotask::`?

Comment: Autotask works fine, but automodule doesn't return anything.

Comment: `autotask` is the official way to do it see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.sphinx.html)

Comment: I saw that, I guessed that I assumed automodule could automatically pick up the tasks, since autotask is designated as the 'manual' method. I'll leave this question up in case there are other ways of doing this, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @KobiK That's not what the documentation says. "With the extension installed autodoc will automatically find task decorated objects..." and "Use .. autotask:: to manually document a task." The automatic part, which looks to be officially supported, does not work. Only the manual part works.

Comment: @Shookit Can you please share link of some sample django project where you are documenting celery tasks using sphinx. I searched a lot, but couldn't find something useful. So, still I am not sure, how I can document celery tasks using sphinx.

Answer (score 3):

Check the official documentation [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/sphinx.html)

Looks like you need to `'celery.contrib.sphinx'` within your `docs/conf.py` file.